# UWP : How to determine 2 TransformGroup is the same approximately?

Tags: c#, uwp, geometry, windows-10-universal

I have 1 shape on canvas.

1. Case 1 : I am using a TransformGroup to new place with rotation
2. Case 2 : I use hand to move and rotate shape from original place to last place in case 1.

I want to check if the shape is laid correctly or not.
So I want to compare 2 TransformGroup value. Do you have any idea about this?

[image]

I also want to handle the shapes which is symmetrical too.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 1):

> So I want to compare 2 TransformGroup value.

I'm not sure how you implement your features, but for comparing the [`TransformGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.transformgroup) value, you could just name the transform objects inside the group and get the properties of each transform for comparing. For example, the following code snippet get the rotate angle and translate value:

XAML

```
<StackPanel Margin="15">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation
                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                Storyboard.TargetName="rotateTransform"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                From="0"
                To="360"
                Duration="0:0:8" />
            <DoubleAnimation
                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                Storyboard.TargetName="translateTransform"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                To="200"
                Duration="0:0:8" />
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Rectangle
        Width="50"
        Height="50"
        Fill="RoyalBlue"
        PointerPressed="StartAnimation" >
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup x:Name="transformgroup">
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" Angle="45" CenterX="25" CenterY="25"   />
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform" X="0" />                    
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>

    <TextBox x:Name="txtAngle" Header="CurrentAngle" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txtX" Header="CurrentX" />
    <Button
        x:Name="btnget"
        Click="btnget_Click"
        Content="gettransform" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind

```
private void StartAnimation(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myStoryboard.Begin();
}

private void btnget_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtAngle.Text= rotateTransform.Angle.ToString();
    txtX.Text = translateTransform.X.ToString();
    //RotateTransform rotatetransget= transformgroup.Children[0] as RotateTransform;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution only for polygon and it correct if the shape is symmetrical.

Just compare transform by compare it points after transform

```
Boolean CompareTransform(TransformGroup transformGroupA, TransformGroup transformGroupB)
{
    if (element is Polygon)
    {
        Polygon p = element as Polygon;
        List<Point> listPointA = new List<Point>();
        List<Point> listPointB = new List<Point>();

        for (int i = 0; i < p.Points.Count; i++)
        {
            Point pointA = transformGroupA.Value.Transform(p.Points[i]);
            Point pointB = transformGroupB.Value.Transform(p.Points[i]);
            listPointA.Add(pointA);
            listPointB.Add(pointB);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < listPointB.Count; i++)
        {
            if (GetDistance(listPointA[0].X, listPointA[0].Y, listPointB[i].X, listPointB[i].Y) < 10)
            {
                List<Point> newList = new List<Point>();
                newList.AddRange(listPointB.GetRange(i, listPointB.Count - i));
                newList.AddRange(listPointB.GetRange(0, i));

                return ComparePointsList(listPointA, newList);

            }
        }


        return false;

    }
    return false;
}            

bool ComparePointsList(List<Point> listA, List<Point> listB)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
        {
            if (GetDistance(listA[i].X, listA[i].Y, listB[i].X, listB[i].Y) > 10)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    double GetDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.Pow(y1 - y2, 2));
    }
```

Are you have any idea for eclipse?